# Setting Value of Char* in Struct in the DLL from C++ to C# Vice Verse (Marshalling/PInvoke)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, marshalling

I currently have a DLL written and there's a struct that I declared that'd be used by both the C# and C++ applications to store information in the memory map files.

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct SHAREDMEMORY_API Data
{
public:

    int getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    int getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    int getExtra() {
        return extra;
    }

    char* getName(){
        printf("Get name value in struct: %s\n", name);
        return name;
    }

    void setKind(int sKind) {
        kind = sKind;
    }

    void setCountry(int scountry) {
        country = scountry;
    }

    void setName(char* sname){
        name = new char[strlen(sname)];
        strcpy(name, sname);
    }

    void deletePointer(){
        delete[] name;
        delete[] type;
        delete[] band;
    }


private:
    int kind;
    int country; 
    int extra;
    char* name;
};
```

These are the methods in the DLL that I exposed so that my C++ exe and C# exe can call.

```
extern "C" void SetData(
int kind,
int country, 
int extra,
char* name)
{
CMutex mutex;   

int size = 1; 
Data* dynamicArray = new Data[size];

if(m_pViewMMFFile)
{
    Data* record = (Data*) m_pViewMMFFile; // Maps the memory mapped file as an Data object array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        dynamicArray[i].setKind(kind);
        printf("setKind: %i\n", kind);
        dynamicArray[i].setCountry(country);
        printf("setCountry: %i\n", country);
        dynamicArray[i].setExtra(extra);
        printf("setExtra: %i\n", extra);
        dynamicArray[i].setName(name);
        printf("setName: %s\n", name);

        record[i] = dynamicArray[i];
    }
    record = dynamicArray;
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    }
    mutex.~CMutex();
}
```

In my C++ main method, I tried to set the data and also tried to retrieve the information and there wasn't any problem in getting back the data that is has set previously. Here's the codes:

```
typedef Data* (*PGETDATAFUN)();
typedef void (*PSETDATAFUN)(int kind,
int country, 
int extra,
char* name);

char buffer[4096];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
bool doneSetting = false;
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary
    ("MemoryMapDLL.dll");
PGETDATAFUN getfuncptr = NULL;
PSETDATAFUN setentityfuncptr = NULL;

if (hModule)
{
    getfuncptr = (PGETDATAFUN) GetProcAddress
        (hModule, "GetData");
    setfuncptr = (PSETDATAFUN) GetProcAddress
        (hModule, "SetData");
}

for(;;){
    UDPServer::MyUDP myudp;
    myudp.getUDP(buffer);

    if (buffer[0] != 0) {
        if (str == "Play") {
            memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
            try {

                if (!getfuncptr)
                {
                    cout << "Error retrieving entity data. \n";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!doneSetting){
                        setfuncptr(1000, 2000, 3000, "Woohyun");
                        doneSetting = true;
                    }
                    Sleep(1000);

                    Data* ed = (Data*)(getfuncptr());
                    printf("Address of Data: %i\n", ed);
                    printf("Size: %i\n", sizeof(Data));
                    printf("Kind of Remote Control: %i\n", ed->kind);
                    printf("Country of Remote Control: %i\n", ed->country);
                    printf("Extra of Remote Control: %i\n", ed->extra);
                    printf("Name of Remote Control: %s\n", ed->name);
                }
            } catch (exception& ex){
                ofstream file;
                file.open("D:\\log.txt");
                file << "Exception found:" << "\n";
                file << ex.what() << "\n";
                file.close();
            }

        }
    }
}

FreeLibrary(hModule);
return 0;
}
```

This is my corresponding struct in C# which is marshaled as a class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    class MarshalClass
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public class Data
        {
            public Int32 kind;

            public Int32 country;

            public Int32 extra;

            public IntPtr name;
        }
      }
    }
```

This is where I tried to do the marshalling in C#.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("MemoryMapDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    extern static void SetData(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int kind,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int country,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int extra,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name
        );

    [DllImport("MemoryMapDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    extern static IntPtr GetData();

    private void UdpMessageSending(string inputMessage)
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);
        udpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 11000);
        Console.WriteLine("Sending UDP Message: " + inputMessage);
        // Sends a message to the host to which you have connected.
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputMessage);
        udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
        udpClient.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            for (; ;)
            {
               string x = Console.ReadLine();

               Program p = new Program();
               p.UdpMessageSending("Play");

               //SetData(1, 2, 225, 2, type, 4, 1, 0, name, 1, 4, band);

               Thread.Sleep(1000);

               IntPtr ptr = GetData();
               Console.WriteLine("Pointer: " + ptr.ToString());


               MarshalClass.Data data = (MarshalClass.Data)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(MarshalClass.Data));
               Console.WriteLine("Data Size in C#: " + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MarshalClass.Data)));

               Console.WriteLine("Kind: " + data.kind);
               Console.WriteLine("Country: " + data.country);
       Console.WriteLine("Extra: " + data.extra);
       IntPtr nameIntPtr = data.name;
               Console.WriteLine("NameIntPtr: " + nameIntPtr);

               string name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(nameIntPtr);
               if (name != null)
               {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
               }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem came when I tried to retrieve the information on the C# side. It wasn't able to retrieve the `char*` name attribute (this happened when it tried to call the `GetData` method in the DLL where it'd throw a `AccessViolationException` error and crashes my application). It was able to retrieve the other attributes that are of integer types, however, without any problems. The same would happen if I tried to set the data in C# and C# would be able to retrieve it back perfectly but when my C++ application tried to retrieve the char* name, the application would crash. However, in my DLL, I was able to print out the address of the name data being stored, hence eliminating the possibility of it being null. So, what could be the possible cause for this? Does anyone know what's the solution for this?

Comment: This starts with a Big Bug, the setName() function has an off-by-one bug.  It must allocate strlen(sname)+1 bytes, one extra for the zero terminator.  The heap corruption this causes just sends the program down into a spiral of undetectable misery that gets ten times as hard to debug when you use pinvoke.  Not being able to reliably release the memory allocated for the data just makes it worse from there.

Comment: I've changed my codes significantly, taking in the advises that you gave and I'm using fixed size character array instead of char pointer and it's working fine now. Thanks for the comment!